# How to create a partition for windows files only

Tags: partitioning

I'm creating partitions for my SSD and I want to create one for Windows files only (boot and other stuff). I don't really have much data now since this is a new drive.

**My question is:** Is it correct to just put the Windows folder (found in C drive) in 1 partition and the other folders like Program files, users, etc in the other partition?

Will the Windows partition require more space as I download more programs (will it add data to that folder after I download apps)?

Comment: Not about the Windows folder per se, which (I believe) averages about 20-25GB by itself, but many programs (or even Windows) will not necessarily let you select where common components or data is stored. And in my experience, it's easy to start running into space problems on a primary Windows partition at 50-60GB. Even if you plan to redirect e.g. Program Files, Users, memory caching, etc. I personally wouldn't settle for anything less than 100GB for C:\.

Comment: Ok. I'll partition it to 100 gb and move all other folders and keep the windows one there alone. If there are storage problems in the future I'll increase its size.